# How to programmatically post reaction to Microsoft channel message?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Using graph api I'm trying to post a reaction (for example a like) but I can't manage to find the right syntax.
If I put a reaction in a message at creation time, it returns an error saying that I can't set the reaction during the creation.

I'm then trying to patch or put the message and it return a 501 without giving the exact reason.
Can someone put a working sample of a valid json ?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not supported in Graph API. We are working on it but do not have a firm timeline to share